# Object vs Document Storage (Databases) = Difference (nosql)?

Tags: database, nosql

i would be thankfull for a short explanation of these different concepts. Wikipedia mentions both in context of NoSQL but I did not find any further information whats the difference between both.

Update regarding the comments:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL#Object_database

vs

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL#Document_store

But the difference is completely unclear to me. (Stackoverflow does not allow me to post two links as newbie so the links are actually disabled)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3691899/whats-difference-between-nosql-db-and-oo-db

Comment: Um, there's no such thing as an object database, but you can actually download and use document databases?

Comment: It would be easier to answer if you have a specific task you are trying to accomplish.  Search engine?  Online forum?  CMS?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Ken! Well actually I only want to learn everything about NoSQL and therefore I am interessted what the difference is. There must be some differences in the term (otherwise wikipedia would not use two terms) and I want to try to unterstand the difference. thanks.

Comment: @Ken, no such thing as an object database? First there's the Wikipedia link, and then there's also db4o (http://www.db4o.com/about/productinformation/db4o/).

Comment: [S3 or DynamoDB?](https://serverless.pub/s3-or-dynamodb/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For most practical purposes, there is no difference - A document is often just a serialized object, and if you only need basic storage, any key/value store can hold objects.

There may be differences in things like how partial updates and queries are handled, but since there is no such thing as standard NoSQL, you get just as many differences between products in the same category.

Comment: There is a huge difference IMHO: references. You might have a library over your document database to make it an object database.